# Select com inner join

Tags: php, mysql, ionic3

Boa tarde, 
 estou fazendo um app onde preciso listar todos cômodos de um usuário e o ultimo consumo registrado de cada cômodo, só que meu código busca errado, se um cômodo tiver mais mais de um consumo ele duplica o mesmo, então gostaria de uma ajuda para arrumar meu comando sql. Segue prints de como fica se tiver mais de um consumo por cômodo:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código que estou usando: 
`SELECT co.id,co.descricao,ca.potencia_atual from comodo co INNER JOIN consumo_atual ca ON ca.Comodo_id = co.id WHERE co.Usuario_id = :id`

Print do esquema das duas tabelas:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode incluir o `GROUP BY`, que agrupa os resultados da busca.

```
SELECT co.id,co.descricao,ca.potencia_atual from comodo co 
INNER JOIN consumo_atual ca ON ca.Comodo_id = co.id 
WHERE co.Usuario_id = :id
GROUP BY co.id,co.descricao,ca.potencia_atual
```

Comment: Infelizmente não deu, oq mudou foi que agora os cômodos duplicados ficaram agrupados, eu gostaria que aparecesse somente os cômodos que o usuário possui mais o ultimo consumo registrado naquele cômodo.

Comment: Não entendi o que você não gostaria que aparecesse no resultado da busca, mas que está aparecendo. Estão aparecendo cômodos que o usuário não possui? Ou não está aparecendo o valor do consumo? Ou você gostaria de uma saída separada com os cômodos que o usuário possui e outra com o consumo?

Comment: se o usuário tiver mais de um consumo registrado em um mesmo comodo no bd, na home lista vai lista o comodo mais de uma vez, um pra cada consumo registrado no bd, então por exemplo, se a sala tiver 2 consumos ela aparecerá duas vezes na home, e eu gostaria q aparecesse somente uma vez listando apenas o ultimo registro do comodo.

Comment: Acho que entendi. Você precisa primeiro verificar qual é o último valor do registro de cada cômodo na tabela consumo_atual e depois disso fazer o inner join. Veja se essa solução funciona: `SELECT co.id,co.descricao,ca.potencia_atual from comodo co 
INNER JOIN
(select comodo_id, potencia_atual, MAX(data_criacao) as maxdata from consumo_atual
gruop by comodo_id, potencia_atual) ca
ON ca.Comodo_id = co.id
WHERE co.Usuario_id = :id`

Comment: infelizmente não funcionou, vou pesquisar um pouco na documentação